# Exception is raised in J2ME when calling a webservice which calls a PHP function selecting accentuated letters from a MySQL table column

Tags: php, web-services, java-me, wsdl, ksoap2

I want to call a `webservice` from a `J2ME` application :

```
public String alimenterBaseDeDonneesEtapeProsp( String login, String password,String adresse,String site)
    {
        Object  resultatRequeteSOAP = null;
        SoapObject objetSOAPEtapeProsp;
        HttpTransport connexionServeur;
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
        String nomService = "urn:Client";
        String urlService = adresse+"/"+site+"/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php";
        String methodeChoisie = "getEtapeProsp";
        try
        {
                    connexionServeur = new HttpTransport(urlService );
                    connexionServeur.debug = true;
                    objetSOAPEtapeProsp = new SoapObject(nomService, methodeChoisie );
                    objetSOAPEtapeProsp.addProperty("user", login);
                    objetSOAPEtapeProsp.addProperty("motpasse",password);
                    System.out.println(objetSOAPEtapeProsp);
                    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapSerializationEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.bodyOut = objetSOAPEtapeProsp;
                    connexionServeur.call(null,envelope);
                    resultatRequeteSOAP = envelope.getResponse();
                    return String.valueOf(resultatRequeteSOAP);
        }
        catch (Exception aE)
        {
             return aE.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

The `ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar` file is already added to the J2ME project.

The wsdl file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions name="Client" 
        targetNamespace="urn:Client" 
        xmlns:typens="urn:Client" 
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
        xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
        xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">

    <!-- partie 2 : Types-->
    <types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            targetNamespace="urn:Client">
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
        ...
    <message name="getEtapeProspRequest">
        <part name="user" type="xsd:string"/>
        <part name="motpasse" type="xsd:string"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getEtapeProspResponse">
        <part name="return" type="xsd:anyType"/>
    </message>
        ...
    <portType name="ClientPort">
             ...
        <operation name="getEtapeProsp">
            <input message="typens:getEtapeProspRequest"/>
            <output message="typens:getEtapeProspResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="ClientBinding" type="typens:ClientPort">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        ...
        <operation name="getEtapeProsp">
            <soap:operation soapAction="EtapeProspAction"/>
            <input name="getEtapeProspRequest">
                <soap:body  use="encoded"   namespace="urn:Client" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </input>
            <output name="getEtapeProspResponse">
                <soap:body  use="encoded" namespace="urn:Client" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>

    <!-- partie 7 : Service -->
    <service name="ClientService">
        <documentation></documentation>
        <!-- partie 8 : Port -->
        <port name="ClientPort" binding="typens:ClientBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://192.168.1.123/imfmobile/webservice/InterfaceTransfererClient.php"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The `PHP` code containing the function which the webservice calls is :

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    $serveurSOAP = new SoapServer('Client.wsdl');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getClient');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getCredit');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getEcheancier');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getUrlPhotos');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getModificationClient');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getModificationCredit');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getModificationEcheance');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getAllPhotoNames');
    $serveurSOAP->addFunction('getEtapeProsp');
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
         $serveurSOAP->handle();
    }
    else
    {
         echo 'désolé, je ne comprends pas les requêtes GET, veuillez seulement utiliser POST';
    }
        ...
        function verifyUser($user, $motpasse) {
        $ok = null ;
        $connec = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306", "root", "mysqlroot");
        mysql_select_db("finance",$connec);
        $query=mysql_query("SELECT  user_code FROM utilisateur WHERE user_login = '".$user."' AND user_passwd = md5('".$motpasse."')");
        if (mysql_num_rows($query)== 1) 
        {
            $ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $ok = $ligne['user_code'] ;
        }   
        return $ok;
    }
        ...
        function getEtapeProsp($user,$motpasse)
    {
        $user_code    = verifyUser($user, $motpasse) ;
        $resultat="";
        if ( $user_code != null) 
        {
            $datejour = date("Y-m-d");
            $connec   = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306", "root", "mysqlroot");
            mysql_select_db("finance",$connec);
            $query    = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM etape_prospection INNER JOIN type_prospection ON etape_prospection.type_prosp_id = type_prospection.type_prosp_id WHERE prosp_id IN (SELECT prosp_id FROM transfert WHERE user_code ='".$user_code ."' AND date_transfert='".$datejour."') order by etape_prospection.prosp_id");
            while($ligne = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                {
                     $resultat .= $ligne['etape_prosp_id'].';';
                     $resultat .= $ligne['type_prosp_lib'].';';
                     $resultat .= convertDateFormatHH($ligne['etape_prosp_date']).';';
                     $resultat .= $ligne['etape_prosp_comment'].';'; // this is the column containing the accentuated letters
                     $resultat .= $ligne['prosp_id'].';';
                     $resultat .= "\r\n";
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $resultat = "Login ou mot de passe incorrect" ;
        }
        return $resultat;
    }
?>
```

As you can see I set the encoding/charset both in the `wsdl` and the `PHP`.

So why this exception is raised when running the J2ME application :

```
expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}SOAP-ENV:Fault>@2:299 in java.io.InputStreamReader@e5125d64)
```

Comment: Are you executing code in Emualator ?

Comment: Of course ! Before installing the app in the phone I must test it first in the emulator ! The problem is that when the MySQL column doesn't contain accentuated letters then there is no exception ; but if I add accentuated letters in the column value then the exception is raised !

Comment: pheromix please ignore my prior answer (I just deleted it) - your `soap:binding` looks indeed OK to me; I missed that by mistake

Comment: I debugged the J2ME code and I found that it's the `call` method which throws the exception : `connexionServeur.call(null,envelope);`. So how to write the call correctly ?

Comment: Even if I set the first argument of the `call` method to "EtapeProspAction" then the exception is always thrown !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell your mysql database / client that you expect to have UTF-8 encoded values (because you insert them as UTF-8 into the SOAP response that is UTF-8 encoded).

Otherwise the SOAP client would see an invalid byte-squence for the letter in question and throw the exception. Please consult your mysql client library manual to specify the encoding.

```
$connec = mysql_connect("192.168.1.123:3306", "root", "mysqlroot");
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $connec);
```

The `mb_convert_encoding` function is only a workaround and you don't fix the root cause, and it can have side-effects you don't want to have.

Answer (score 1):

I passed the `PHP` function `mb_convert_encoding` to $ligne['etape_prosp_comment'] and the problem is resolved.